# Prevent Jade interpolation for script template

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, underscore.js, pug

I am using node.js and express.j s to render an index.jade page which contains several script blocks taht contain templates to be used via backbone and underscore. The issue I am facing is that due to the inclusiong of <%= %> style variables within the templates, the Jade rendering is failing. The following code snippet causes a syntax error:

```
script#tpl-things-list-item(type='text/template')
  td 
    a(href=<%= _id %>) link text
  td <%= name %>
  td <%= age %>
```

Note that it is only a problem when I use a variable inside the href value, if I remove the entire href, this snippet works just fine.  Is there a way to work around this? I'd like to continue using Jade to define the templates as it is very concise but this is a show stopper.

Comment: I can't figure this out either. strange.

Answer (score 3):

Got it.

```
!!! 5
html(lang='en')
    head
        title= title
    body
        h1= "Hello World!"
        script#tpl-things-list-item(type='text/template')
            td
                a(href!="<%= _id %>") link text
            td <%= name %>
            td <%= age %>
```

Comment: What does the "!" before the "=" in the href call do?

Comment: it generates 'unescaped executable code' https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme

Comment: for me, this prints the literal string, e.g. `a href!="<%= _id %>"` instead of `a href="123"`.  any suggestions?  my full script is: `script(type='text/template')
a(href!="<%= _id%>")<%= _id%>`

Comment: i found a workaround by just using | but that doesn't seem as clean :/  e.g. `|<a href=<%= _id %>> <%= _id%></a>`

Comment: Seems like _just_ the quotes around the href value should be enough, since client-side templating is _not_ "unescaped executable code". I've successfully used angular.js interpolation in jade templates with just a(href="{{ url }}").